# Kaminari link_to_next_page and link_to_previous_page from a service client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, pagination, kaminari

I have a service that uses [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) for pagination. The `index` controller action for the service looks like this.

```
respond_to :json, xml
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @search = Product.search_for(params[:query], load: true)
  else
    @search = Product.all
  end

  @products = Kaminari.paginate_array(@search).page(params[:page]).per(20)
end
```

i am using [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) to create json views. The `index.rabl` looks like this:

```
collection @products => :products
  attributes :title, :price, :category_id
```

I also have a client that consumes the service; part of the client's controller action that consumes the service looks like this:

```
def index
  ## other code ##
  response = HTTParty.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products.json")
  ## other code ##
end
```

I want pagination done on the server side so i have not installed kaminari on the client. I can choose which page i want by adding `page` parameter on the url like this:

```
 response = HTTParty.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products.json?page=3")
```

and it works. What can i do on either the service side or the client to achieve next page and previous page without installing kaminari on the client.